# CAST Function returns data as NULL

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks

When I use the CAST function in azure data bricks it returns value as 'NULL'.  The data type is varchar for column month.

```
select distinct CAST(month AS DATE) from date
```

Below is how the values are currently there in month column and I want this to convert it to 'yyyy-MM-dd'

[image]

Comment: None of those are dates, dates have a Year, Month, *and day*; you have no day.

Comment: Also, please don't replace textual data with an image; please put the text back.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will bring the expected data,

```
select distinct to_date(CONCAT(SUBSTR(month,1,3),',',SUBSTR(month,-4)),'MMM,yyyy') AS Date
```

from dbdbCommonStgstore.MSPeople_History_Domain